# What is this ruby/bash command performing?

Tags: ruby, bash

Can anyone plz explain what does perform the following command ?

```
StringIO.new("#!/bin/sh -e\nexec /usr/bin/ssh -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no \"$@\"\n")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It makes a file-like string object. ([`StringIO`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/stringio/rdoc/StringIO.html)).

```
require 'stringio'
s = StringIO.new("a\n")
s << "b\n";
```

You can later get the content of the StringIO object using [`StringIO#string` method](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/stringio/rdoc/StringIO.html#method-i-string).

```
s.string # => "a\nb\n";
```

---

IMO, the string is intended to be written to the file, then executed by shell.